# Facebook fan gate not working

Tags: php, facebook

So I create a Facebook app for a page tab with "fan gate", but the problem is that the `signed_request` is not working, so I cannot receive users page like status. I always get the `Not in iframe!` message, but the page opens in iframe...

This is my code of the main page:

```
<?php

function parsePageSignedRequest() {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    $encoded_sig = null; $payload = null;
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
    return $data;
  }
  return false;
}


if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest()) {
  if($signed_request->page->liked) {
    include 'fan.php';
  } else {
     include 'no_fan.php';
  }
} else {
  echo 'Not in iframe!';
}


?>
```

Comment: I think you condition `if($signed_request = parsePageSignedRequest())` is wrong. What do you wan to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The signed_request is available only for the first page loaded in the page tab.

If, in your iframe, you perform a redirection before calling your script, the signed_request will disappear from $_REQUEST.

The solution is to put the signed_request (at least the infos you need) in the session everytime it's available, and then fetch what you want in this session instead of the signed_request directly.

And maybe you could try to use the Facebook PHP SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0). It's quite simple to use, and there is a getSignedRequest() method that will avoid you to make mistakes while manipulating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the signed_request on only the initial page load of the app - facebook post's data only to the first page it loads into it's iframe.

I usually work around this using sessions:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {

    $encoded_sig = null;
    $payload = null;
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));

    if($data->page->liked) {            
        $_SESSION['liked'] = true;          
    }           

    } else {
        $_SESSION['liked'] = false;
    }

}
```

Bear in mind with this approach though that because Facebook require SSL you will have problems with some versions of Safari blocking all 3rd party cookies - so your app in the iframe wont have permission to create the session cookie needed. This will mean soon as your users navigate off the first page the signed_request from facebook and the session both vanish...

To get around this I tend to go old school & append the session_id to each URL in the app - so you need to append `?PHPSESSID=<?php echo session_id(); ?>` to each URL or form action etc...

Additionally in your scripts or config you need to tell PHP to use cookie-less sessions.
I use:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 1);
```

Normally appending the session ID would be a bit ugly - but as you're in an iframe noone really sees the URL anyway.